# Linked Server is not working in Trigger

Tags: sql, timeout, linked-server

I have a Linked Server that executes correctly in a Query, but when i tried to execute it inside a Trigger I was getting this:

```
Error Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider
Error Message: The operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI" for linked server [LINKEDSERVER] was unable to begin a distributed transaction.
... Returned Message "The Transaction Manager has disabled its support for remote/network transactions"
```

Then I activated the DTC on both servers:

Here is how to configure MSDTC:

1. Go to Control Panel -> Administrative Tools
2. Open Component Services
3. Expand Component Services -> Computers -> My Computer -> Distributed  Transaction Coordinator
4. Right click Local DTC
5. Click on Properties
6. Go to Security

And now I get this:

```
Error Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider.
Error Message: Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completition of th eoperation or the server is not responding.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have it working now, i just added a firewall rule at the remote server to MSDTC.EXE, inbound and outbound.

Thanks